# Comparing two string arrays and returning key of not found element using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

Requirement:
Create checkboxes for each letter typed in the textbox, and if backspace is pressed remove the checkbox.

Code provided below, doesn't work if alphabet **p** is removed from the word **apple**

```js
var diffIndexes = [];
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
  var source = this;
  return this.filter(function(i) {
    if (a.indexOf(i) < 0) {
      diffIndexes.push(source.indexOf(i));
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
};

values = ['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'].diff(['a', 'p', 'l', 'e']);
console.log(diffIndexes)
```

Expected: Return index: `[2]`

Actual: Return index: `[]`

Comment: Your title is completely different to the description, where you state you want to create and remove checkboxes. Also note that if all you want to do is compare arrays then jQuery is not what you need, as that's primarily a ODM manipulation framework.

Comment: I am done with creating the checkboxes, but I need help while removing those checkboxes.

Comment: @RoshanSuvarna I saw the unaccept, were you having problems with the answer?

Comment: Yes @CertainPerformance, when same alphabets are present in the array, it doesn't work as expected. For example, from word **dad** if I remove **d** from start, it returns [2] when it should return [0]

Comment: Oh, so you don't just want to check whether the element being iterated over is included in the other, and the relative position of each element needs to be preserved - see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While iterating over both arrays, compare the full array element against the element at `arrWithHoles[0]`. If they're different, we're at a hole, and can push to the array to return; else, there's a match, so shift out the first element in the `arrWithHoles` so that the next element can be compared properly:

```js
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
  const arrWithHoles = a.slice(); // don't mutate the input
  const base = this;
  const holeIndicies = [];
  base.forEach((char, i) => {
    if (arrWithHoles[0] !== char) {
      holeIndicies.push(i);
    } else {
      // Character found at start of other array - they match up, remove:
      arrWithHoles.shift();
    }
  });
  return holeIndicies;
};

console.log(
  ['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'].diff(['a', 'p', 'l', 'e']),
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].diff(['a', 'd', 'e']),
  ['d', 'a', 'd'].diff(['a', 'd'])
);
```